# How can I force Ubuntu to ignore a particular WiFi router/SSID?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wireless-networking, router, ubuntu-12.04

One of my neighbors has a particularly promiscuous router with a fairly slow connection.  This means that sometimes one of my machines will happen to pick up their connection instead of my far better (and more secure) one, because the signal strength is higher in some places.

How can I tell Ubuntu to just ignore their wireless network?  Can I block it by the SSID?

Comment: Does it connect to it automatically? What happens if you delete the wireless profile for it?

Comment: I have deleted it a couple of times, but whenever it is the strongest signal, it gets picked up again.

Comment: Log on to their wireless access point/router and put in a passphrase. Put a sticky note on their door with the passphrase. :)

Comment: If I knew which door, I might.  But it could be any of about nine residences.

Answer (score 3):

- right click on network manager
- select edit connection
- press wireless tab
- select your neighbor connection --> edit
- uncheck connect automatically --> apply

that should do it.